# Is there any way to remove the first occurence of pattern by sed?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

This is a test file:

```
xxx
hello 
hello 
others
```

I want to use sed:

```
sed -i '/hello/d' the_test_file
```

This will remove all lines contain "hello", so how to just remove the first line contains "hello"?

I think sed cant do it, but with perl i can. it's like:

```
perl -00 -pe "s/hello//" the_test_file > /tmp/file && mv /tmp/file the_test_file
```

Comment: please stop changing the question. My answer will not be accurate if you keep changing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Show the original content of the file.

```
cat the_test_file
1
2
3
popo
hello 1
hello 2
others
```

Show the result after running the sed command

```
sed -e '0,/^hello/{//d;}' the_test_file
1
2
3
popo
hello 2
others
```

To finally answer your question

NOTE: thanks to jaypal

```
sed -i"bak" -e '0,/^hello/{//d;}' the_test_file
```

Comment: This would remove lines before `hello`. Test it against my test data.

Comment: sorry, he kept changing the question, the original test data was not like it is now.

Comment: no biggie .. `sed -i"bak" '0,/^hello/{//d;}' ff` will eliminate the second pass of moving the file. `-i"bak"` will backup the original file and update the current file. :)

Answer (score 1):

To remove the first hello

```
sed -e "/hello/ N;n;d;" the_test_file
```

To remove the second hello

```
sed -e "/hello/ N;n;n;d;" the_test_file
```

If there are more than 2 lines of hello consecutively, and want to retain the first hello and delete the rest

```
sed -e ":loop" -e "/hello/ N; s/\(hello.*\)\n\(hello.*\)/\1/" -e "t loop" the_test_file
```

If there are more than 2 lines of hello consecutively, and want to retain the last hello only

```
sed -e ":loop" -e "/hello/ N; s/\(hello.*\)\n\(hello.*\)/\2/" -e "t loop" the_test_file
```

the_test_file

```
xxx
hello1
hello2
hello3
others
```

Answer (score 0):

`awk` solution:

```
$ cat file
something
hello 1
else
hello 2
others
hello 3

$ awk '/hello/ && ++c==1{next}1' file
something
else
hello 2
others
hello 3
```

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick (but doesn't generalize easily):

```
$ sed -e '1,/hello/p' -e '1,/hello/d' -e '/hello/d' <<!
> xxx
> hello 
> hello 
> others
!
xxx
hello 
others
$
```

The logic is to print the lines from line 1 to the first line containing 'hello'; then delete those lines (so the automatic print does not happen); thereafter, simply delete the lines matching 'hello'.